# Any way to get this div to pop out of its parent while preserving scrolling?

Tags: css

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/FUdcU/1/

Is there a way to get the .fake-drop to display outside the bottom of the .modal-body and over the .modal-footer while still preserving the vertical scrolling in the .modal-body?

HTML:

```
<div aria-hidden="false" class="fade hide modal in" id="modal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" style="display: block;">
  <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="" class="form-horizontal progressify" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="video-form" method="post">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button aria-hidden="" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">×</button>
      <h3>header</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
      <div id="drop-container">
        <input type="text" id="text"/>
        <div class="fake-drop">
          <div class="drop-row">some row1</div>
          <div class="drop-row">some row2</div>
          <div class="drop-row">some row3</div>
          <div class="drop-row">some row4</div>
          <div class="drop-row">some row5</div>
          <div class="drop-row">some row6</div>
          <div class="drop-row">some row7</div>
          <div class="drop-row">some row8</div>
          <div class="drop-row">some row9</div>
          <div class="drop-row">some row0</div>
          <div class="drop-row">some row11</div>
          <div class="drop-row">some row12</div>
          <div class="drop-row">some row13</div>
          <div class="drop-row">some row14</div>
          <div class="drop-row">some row15</div>
          <div class="drop-row">some row16</div>
          <div class="drop-row">some row17</div>
          <div class="drop-row">some row18</div>
          <div class="drop-row">some row19</div>
          <div class="drop-row">some row20</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <h4>hey look, there's content under here!</h4>
      <h4>hey look, there's content under here!</h4>
      <h4>hey look, there's content under here!</h4>
      <h4>hey look, there's content under here!</h4>
      <h4>hey look, there's content under here!</h4>
      <h4>hey look, there's content under here!</h4>
      <h4>hey look, there's content under here!</h4>
      <h4>hey look, there's content under here!</h4>
      <h4>hey look, there's content under here!</h4>
      <h4>hey look, there's content under here!</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a aria-hidden="true" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" tabindex="-2">Cancel</a>
      <input class="btn btn-primary" name="commit" type="submit" value="Save">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css');

.container {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
h4{
    margin-top: 50px;
}
form{
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.drop-container{
    position: relative;
}
.fake-drop{
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 250px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 15px;
    box-shadow: 1px 3px 10px 1px #ccc;
}
.drop-row{
    padding: 2px 5px;
}
.drop-row + .drop-row{
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

Comment: There's a reason that code should be included within the question rather than simply linked to on jsfiddle, etc. (Hence the error message you attempted to circumvent.) The idea being that questions (and indeed answers) are free-standing and not dependant on external resources that may atrophy over time.

Answer (score 0):

```
.modal-body {
position: relative;
height: 200px;
}

.fake-drop{
position: fixed;
top: 105px;
left: 30px;
}
```

if I understand what your asking.
Change variables as required.

http://jsfiddle.net/FUdcU/4/

With Jquery scrollTop

http://jsfiddle.net/FUdcU/5/

Comment: Doesn't seem to work: http://jsfiddle.net/FUdcU/3/  The fake-drop is still tucked under the .modal-footer

Comment: Are you saying you want the menu to scroll with the inside content but be part of the outside body?
Try my amendments above.

Comment: Almost...I want it to show outside like that, but still scroll with .modal-body

Comment: You will need script to do this see new fiddle for the general idea.